# How to reconstruct a radially symmetric image from one projection using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have one projection from a radially symmetric image (or data), and I need to reconstruct from this projection the 2D image or data. In order to check how to do it I tried for example to reconstruct an image of a circle from one projection. I created the projections matrix of the circle, which I need to send to iradon, by repmat the vector of the sum of the circle (the vector of summations along the columns of the circle image) to 180 columns of the projections matrix, in order to mimic as if I have 180 projections for theta=0:179 degrees. However, the reconstructed circle achieved in this way was degraded with comparison to the one which was reconstructed using the projections matrix created by radon.m (instead of having a white circle like the original, I got a circle consisting of whitish-grayish rings) . How can I get better results for the reconstruction of a radially symmetric image from one projection?

The code of radon.m and of my version of radon, for one projection of a radially symmetric image, are copied below.

### radon.m:

```
function PR = radon(IMG, THETA)

% pad the image with zeros

    [iLength, iWidth] = size(IMG);
    iDiag = sqrt(iLength^2 + iWidth^2);
    LengthPad = ceil(iDiag - iLength) + 2;
    WidthPad = ceil(iDiag - iWidth) + 2;
    padIMG = zeros(iLength+LengthPad, iWidth+WidthPad);
    padIMG(ceil(LengthPad/2):(ceil(LengthPad/2)+iLength-1), ...
        ceil(WidthPad/2):(ceil(WidthPad/2)+iWidth-1)) = IMG;

%create the projections matrix

    n = max(size(padIMG)); 
    x = linspace(-1,1,n);
    [X1,Y1] = meshgrid(x,x);
    n = length(THETA);
    PR = zeros(max(size(padIMG)),n);
    for i = 1:n
        theta = -THETA(i)*pi/180;
        X = cos(theta)*X1 + -sin(theta)*Y1;
        Y = sin(theta)*X1 + cos(theta)*Y1;
        tmpimg = interp2(X1,Y1,padIMG,X,Y);
        tmpimg(isnan(tmpimg)) = 0;
        PR(:,i) = (sum(tmpimg))';
    end
```

### my radon:

```
function PR = radonOfRadialSymmetricImage(IMG,theta)

%pad image with zeros 

    [iLength, iWidth] = size(IMG);
    iDiag = sqrt(iLength^2 + iWidth^2);
    LengthPad = ceil(iDiag - iLength) + 2;
    WidthPad = ceil(iDiag - iWidth) + 2;
    padIMG = zeros(iLength+LengthPad, iWidth+WidthPad);
    padIMG(ceil(LengthPad/2):(ceil(LengthPad/2)+iLength-1), ...
        ceil(WidthPad/2):(ceil(WidthPad/2)+iWidth-1)) = IMG;

%create the projections matrix

    n = length(theta);
    PR = zeros(max(size(padIMG)), n);
    projectionData=(sum(padIMG))';
    PR= repmat(projectionData,1,n);
```

Comment: So you are asking why your code is not as good as the one by matlab?

Comment: I ask how to make my code as good as the one by matlab. For a radially symmetric image for each angle the projection should be the same, so it's enough to have one projection and to copy it's data for each angle. So why the result is not as good as with actually taking a projection for each angle, and how can I make it better?

Comment: Code looks fine. I am guessing it may have something to do with something that is not in the code you show. Can you post full functions?

Comment: this is the full function except the part of padding the image with zeros which is the following:

Comment: [iLength, iWidth] = size(IMG);
        iDiag = sqrt(iLength^2 + iWidth^2);
        LengthPad = ceil(iDiag - iLength) + 2;
        WidthPad = ceil(iDiag - iWidth) + 2;
        padIMG = zeros(iLength+LengthPad, iWidth+WidthPad);
        padIMG(ceil(LengthPad/2):(ceil(LengthPad/2)+iLength-1), ...
            ceil(WidthPad/2):(ceil(WidthPad/2)+iWidth-1)) = IMG;

Comment: Hello Ander, I edited my original post for the full functions. You can try use each function on an image of a white circle and then iradon each of the created projections matrices and see the difference in the reconstructions by yourself. I thought maybe I should somehow incorporate into my code the effects that the rotation and interp2 cause to the image, but still haven't figure out how to do it  having only one projection of the original image.